# How is "This" assigned when calling an anonymous function using "Call"?

Tags: javascript, oop, call, this

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var animals = [
  {species: 'Lion', name: 'King'},
  {species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    this.print = function () {
      console.log('#' + i  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);
    }
    this.print();
  }).call(animals[i], i);
}
```

In the example above, how is "this" being used in the anonymous function inside the "animals" loop? I am curious as to why "this" is referencing the animal object instead of the window.

If I were, for example, to remove **animals[i]** from the arguments, then everything is undefined. Does that mean that anonymous functions derive their "identity" from the first parameter they receive or is something else going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this part:

```
  }).call(animals[i], i);
```

By calling with `.call()`, the value for `this` is specified explicitly.

There are two similar functions available from the `Function` prototype: `.call()` and `.apply()`.  They both allow a function (any function, anonymous or not — there's no real difference) to be invoked with some particular value (a reference to an object) as `this`.

The value of `this` is **always** set one way or another when a function is invoked.  If the reference to the function is determined by a `.` or `[ ]` expression:

```
something.fn( whatever );

something[ expression ](whatever);
```

then the value of `this` is the value of the base object ("something" in the above examples).  Mr. Eich calls that the "receiver", which makes sense if you think of function calls like Smalltalk messages.

If you call a function without a base object, then the value of `this` is either the global object, or `null` if you're in "strict" mode.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this explained in the [documentation of `function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) you quote yourself?

> ```
> fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `thisArg` The value of `this` provided for the call to fun. [...]

and later:

> **Description**
>
> You can assign a different `this` object when calling an existing function.

So you are right, `animals[i]` is used as `this` inside a function. You can treat it as implicit, hidden parameter that always has `this` name.

Comment: It goes on to say that, "Passing the object as this value was not strictly necessary, but is done for explanatory purpose.", but if I remove that argument everything is undefined. That's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `call` which is defined as:

`call(thisScope, args)`

So the fact you're passing in `animal[i]` as `thisScope` means `this == animal[i]`.